# Size of instanced objects based on subdivision levels

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

Is it possible to change the size of instanced objects as the subdivision level of a mesh changes? Like a higher subdivision creating smaller instances and a low-level subdivision level creating larger instances. In the setup below, the size of the instances stays the same as I change the subdivision level of a plane.

[image: Instances1]
[image: Instances2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this task with the help of the node `Face Area`. In any case, it works relatively well in your use case or with quads:

[image]

Here I capture the value *Area* before the subdivision with `Capture Attribute`.

After the subdivision I divide this value by the newly created size for *Area* and power this value again with $0.5$. This value must also be captured with `Capture Attribute` in the geometry, because you use `Mesh to Points` afterwards.

This way the size of the cone remains constant in relation to the original face.

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>

Answer (score 4):

You could use the captured *Face Area* of the mesh on which your instances are generated, (green
nodes, below):

[image]

The linear scale of your instances will vary as the square-root of the area, to keep them in proportion:

[image]

Comment: Ah, sure! ...it's even easier! Once again, I have thought too complicated.

Comment: @quellenform  Ahh!... crossed wires! It took me a couple of moments to spot why yours was any more complicated than mine..  no great shakes, and your pictures are prettier :) You get this one, IMO.